# Gradle "test" task returns "Test events were not received"

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm developing a custom language support plugin for IntelliJ following the [IntelliJ tutorial](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/custom-language-support-tutorial.html) (not strictly because I'm adapting it to my language, but as strictly as possible). Now I'm trying to write some tests but I can't even do a little POC because when I try to run the tests I see a message saying: "Tests events were not received".
[image: Running tests on IntelliJ]
For developing my tests I'm following the [IntelliJ guide](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/docs/intellij/parsing-test.html) as well, and my test class is [BloblangParsingTest](https://github.com/pcha/intellij-bloblang-support/blob/add-tests/src/test/java/org/pcha/benthos/language/BloblangParsingTest.java).

My code is visible on [GitHub](https://github.com/pcha/intellij-bloblang-support/tree/add-tests) in the branch add-tests. I also added a [github action to run the tests](https://github.com/pcha/intellij-bloblang-support/runs/5703126255?check_suite_focus=true) and I'm getting the same result (the message mentioned above seems to be given by IntelliJ, but the console outputs are the same).
[image: GitHub action output]

Comment: Is it TestNG? Here is a similar bug in IntelliJ: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-221159

Comment: No, I'm not using TestNg and I don't thin that it's a problem of IntelliJ because the github action does't work neither,

Comment: @pcha, Hi, have you found a solution? Thanks.

Comment: No, I didn't find the solution yet, I have the project stopped.